# Node-cron jobs running on fixed week-days

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-cron

I know this might sound a bit dumb, but can I use node-cron to create two crone-jobs to run on two days of the week which are non-consecutives? Do I need to call two CronJob functions, or is there a way to use only one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Node-cron uses the same rules as [crontab](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s2-autotasks-cron-configuring.html), so you can set a rule like this:

```
cron.schedule('30 3 * * sun,tue', function(){
  console.log('running a task at 3:30 on Sunday and Tuesday');
});
```

Note that this is only if you want to run the same job on both days. If you wan to run different jobs you have to create different tasks.

Comment: Node-corn absolutely uses the corntab rules, to achieve your desired rule follow the easy link below and create your job. https://crontab.guru/#30_3_*_*_sun,sat